# Using PyQT for a command prompt (Python) program

Tags: python, pyqt

How exactly would I go about doing this? Any advice would help

Comment: First, what have you tried. Second, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Well..in the command prompt you have to input a bunch of filenames and directories and files you want to open and what not..Instead I wanted to create radio buttons which displayed all the directories we have..and allow you to choose from them

Comment: -1 because question contains no information about what the poster has tried, and has given very little information about their specific problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`QtGui.QCoreApplication()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html)

Its intended for console applications that will not need to use QWidgets. Just create it like you would a normal app, create the rest of your app as normal using QObjects, signals and slots. Start an event loop as normal.

Nothing really changes when you write a console based app aside from the fact that you can't use QWidgets.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Hello(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(Hello, self).__init__()
        self.msg = msg
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.say)
        self.timer.start(500)
        self.i = 0

    def say(self):
        print self.msg
        self.i += 1
        if self.i > 5:
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    hello = Hello("Hello World!")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: BTW, I was feeling really generous because I was just about to hit 10k rep points :-)

Comment: I translated this example to PySide2 and Python 3: https://gist.github.com/8Observer8/3a88bb6b664fbcf568367f99b96b637f

Answer (score 0):

Start the program by opening a file selector dialog (QFileDialog).